# Intent filter to match pattern data from URL query, when opening links in activity

Tags: android, android-intent, pattern-matching, intentfilter

I want to create an activity that opens only when links with a specific URL are clicked.
For example: i want to open http://mysite.xyz/test?param=val#myid=12345 with my app (activity), but http://mysite.xyz/test?other=stuff i want to be opened with default browser.

I'm trying to create an intent filter like this:

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="mysite.xyz"
                  android:pathPattern="????" />
            ...
   </intent-filter>
```

My problem is that android:pathPattern or pathPrefix do not (seam to) verify the query string (any text after the ? or the last /).
Is there a solution for this filtering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I think you can handle the links based on the URL path, up to the "?" or the last "/". Then, in your activity, check the last part (after ? or last /) and if it doesn't match your criteria, you can redirect the user back to the default browser.

Comment: Well, that is the only workaround I've found so far. But i believe that if the user has 2 or more browsers, the message "Choose app to open..." will appear again (and I personally hate that).

Comment: The chooser dialog will show up only when multiple browser apps are installed. So, the user experience remains the same if your app does receive the intent and redirect it to android.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **android:ssp**, **android:sspPrefix** and **android:sspPattern** attributes.
But it works only in 4.4 and higher.